# jquery validation with user name and password

Tags: jquery, validation

am having trouble with my validation code. it is not detecting white space. please help 
here is my validation code

```
$('#login_btn').click(function(){
        var userName=$('#txtUsername').val();
        var passWord=$('#txtPassword').val();

       if(userName==""){
          $('.error_message_login').fadeIn(100);
          return false;
        }

     });
});
```

it is not detecting white space.that is when i enter just some white space and submitted so it is not detecting..
so please let me know any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is working please check this code using **$.trim**

```
$('#login_btn').click(function(){
        var userName=$('#txtUsername').val();
        var passWord=$('#txtPassword').val();

       if($.trim(userName)==""){
          $('.error_message_login').fadeIn(100);
          return false;
        }

     });
});
```

Check this on **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJ5XV/)**

Answer (score 3):

you need to trim the input, String has a [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method but is not supported in IE < 9 so use jQuery's trim method [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
$('#login_btn').click(function(){
        var userName= $.trim($('#txtUsername').val());
        var passWord=$('#txtPassword').val();

       if(userName==""){
          $('.error_message_login').fadeIn(100);
          return false;
        }

     });
});
```